# Jquery img preload not working in FireFox

Tags: jquery-effects, jquery, jquery-load

I recently did a small jQuery snippet that allows me to show a loading img until the real image is loaded.

The snippet seems to work in Safari, Chrome but not FireFox.

FireFox only displays a `loading` alt and never switches to the loaded image.

**Here is the snippet**

```
var loading = $('<img src="/media/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
    $('.thumbnail').each(function(){
        var loadIMG = loading.clone();
            $(this).after(loadIMG).load(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn('fast');
                loadIMG.hide();
        }).hide();
    });
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you wrapping in a ready method ?

Comment: I am yes, $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what exactly is happing on FF but below can be one of the problem. From [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> It is possible that the load event
>   will not be triggered if the image is
>   loaded from the browser cache. To
>   account for this possibility, we can
>   use a special load event that fires
>   immediately if the image is ready.
>   event.special.load is currently
>   available as a plugin.

Here's the [link](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js) for plugin.

Edit:

Based on comments from load event, try below:

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function(){
        var loadIMG = loading.clone();
            $(this).after(loadIMG).load(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn('fast');
                loadIMG.hide();
        }).hide();
        if (this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

Of course, the plug-in seems to be doing same thing along with handling some other scenarios as well as.

Comment: Thanks, I just amended the original text, it never switches from the alt to the loaded image.

Comment: @ApPeL, above can be the issue - unless load is not triggered on the image, you are not going to see loaded image. Try above plugin and see if it works or not.

Comment: The above plugin causes all my other jQuery stuff to not work.

Comment: @ApPel, plugin seems to be straight-forward. Perhaps, you can try similar code your self - I have edited the answer to list the code.